# How can I coax Spring Data to show me mongo's query plan (a.k.a cursor.explain())

Tags: spring, mongodb, jersey, spring-data

I am writing an API with Spring/Mongo/Jersey to do CRUD on a POJO that has a generic map of properties like this:

```
public class Thing {
    private String id;

    @Indexed
    private Map<String,String> properties;
...
```

This is working great to return items.  My resource code looks like this:

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("properties.name", "vlad the impaler");
return Response.ok(myService.queryThings(query)).build();
```

And my abstract DAO looks like this:

```
public List<T> find(Query query) {
        return mongoOps.find(query, clazzOfItem);
}
```

What I can't tell is if the **@Indexed** annotation is working.  I'd like to try **explain**, (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/), but I don't see any examples that show me how to call the lower level driver API from spring data.

I'd like to be able to turn on debugging like so:

```
public List<T> find(Query query) {
        if (debugOn) {
            String queryPathDetails = mongoOps.executeCommand( /*NOW WHAT??*/ ).toString();
            logger.log(queryPathDetails);
        }
        return mongoOps.find(query, clazzOfItem);
}
```

Any help you can provided will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't provide support for that yet, but you could simply set a breakpoint [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/a86d704becb8e2bdc9bbc07108efaaee5f195c8b/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.java#L2217) 
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.QueryCursorPreparer.prepare(..)

In the debugger of your choice you can then simply execute a

```
cursor.explain()
```

e.g. via the eclipse display view.

Comment: can we do the same for aggregation query ??because i am not able to do it for aggregation queries,it works fine with normal queries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
public Object explainQuery(Query query) {
        //Not sure this is safe, please comment if there is a better way!
        String collectionName =  clazzOfItem.getSimpleName().toLowerCase();
        DBCollection collection = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName);
        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(query.getQueryObject());
        return cursor.explain();
}
```

so going back to the DAO code I have listed above, I can now do this:

```
public List<T> find(Query query) {
    if (debugOn) {
        Object queryPlan = explainQuery(query);
        logger.log(queryPlan);
    }
    return mongoOps.find(query, clazzOfItem);
}
```

Any help you can provided will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

As of mongo-java-driver 4.2 this can be done through the [`FindIterable`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/#explain) and [`AggregateIterable`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/aggregation/#explain-an-aggregation) API, which is exposed by [`MongoOperations#getCollection`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoOperations.html#getCollection-java.lang.String-).

```java
Criteria criteria = Criteria.where("properties.name").is("vlad the impaler");
String collectionName = MongoCollectionUtils.getPreferredCollectionName(Thing.class);

// using FindIterable with Spring Data MongoDB Query object
Query query = Query.query(criteria);
Document queryPlanFind = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName)
        .find(query.getQueryObject())
        .explain(ExplainVerbosity.ALL_PLANS_EXECUTIONS);

// using AggregateIterable with Spring Data MongoDB Aggregation object
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(Aggregation.match(criteria));
Document queryPlanAggregation = mongoOps.getCollection(collectionName)
        .aggregate(aggregation.toPipeline(Aggregation.DEFAULT_CONTEXT))
        .explain(ExplainVerbosity.ALL_PLANS_EXECUTIONS);
```