# How to get the query statistics of mongodb using SpringBoot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, logging, datasource, execution-time

Our SpringBoot Microservice project uses Mongo repository, and Mongo template. We are trying to log statistics like execution time and number of documents returned while running the microservice.

For sql query statistics we are using datasource proxy or p6spy libraries. Are there any similar libraries for mongodb?

Is there any way to log the results of "explain" on a given mongodb query using SpringBoot?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. A similar question has been asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28818083/how-can-i-coax-spring-data-to-show-me-mongos-query-plan-a-k-a-cursor-explain/28828358